# Questions about "utiliser au micro-ondes"

Tags: prépositions

The cover of my round tupperware (ie, reusable plastic food container) says the following:

[image]

> UNSCREW LID BEFORE MICROWAVING
>   Dévisser le couvercle avant d' utiliser au micro-ondes

This brought a number of questions to my mind.

TOPIC 1: PREPOSITIONS

> utiliser au micro-ondes

The wordreference page for utiliser doesn't really help me understand what prepositions can follow after "utiliser". (In fact, the example sentences only have "utiliser" followed by "pour" -- never "à"!)

I can certainly guess what "utiliser au micro-ondes" means, especially given that the English is there, too. But I would prefer to learn some grammar / principle underneath this, rather than guessing.

1. What meaning or "feeling" does "au micro-ondes" give? Is it one of the following?

   - Is it "using at the microwave" (ie, literal word-for-word
     translation)?
   - Is it "using in-the-manner-of-microwaving"?
   - Is "utiliser à + [noun]" a set expression meaning "using with a/the/some [noun]",
     and wordreference was incorrect for not having an entry for it?
2. Why is it "**au** micro-ondes", instead of some other possibilities?

If I were to translate this into English, I would say "using in a microwave" ("***à un*** micro-ondes") or "using in your microwave" ("***à votre*** micro-ondes") or "using in microwaves" (maybe "***à des*** micro-ondes" or "***aux*** micro-ondes").

I don't think English would say "using in **the** microwave". Does French use the word "the" in a way that sounds strange in English?

3. How strange would it be if the lid instead said "d'utiliser ***dans*** le micro-ondes" or "d'utiliser ***dans*** un micro-ondes"?
4. The wordreference page for micro-ondes seems to have a different definition for "un micro-ondes" and "une micro-ondes", though I can't understand what the difference is:

[image]

Anyways, the male version says: "(four à micro-ondes)", which makes me think, what would "avant d'utiliser **à** micro-ondes" mean?

TOPIC 2: UNSTATED OBJECT

I learned that French often requires some kind of object, where English leaves it out:

In English: I'm going!
In French: J'y vais! ("I'm going there!")

In English: I know!
In French: Je le sais! ("I know it!")

I had come to think that French *always* requires this "fuller" sentence that includes the object. So I'm surprised that it's "utiliser au micro-ondes".

5. Why does "utiliser" in "utiliser au micro-ondes" not require an object for "utiliser"?

Comment: "à" is used a lot for cooking. After "*réchauffer*" or "*cuire*" you can use "*À la poêle*", "*à la casserole*", "*au feu de bois*" "*au four*", "*au micro-onde*", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Utiliser* does not take an indirect complement, so there is no preposition that is particularly associated with it. The following complement is a *complément circonstanciel*, not a *complément d'objet indirect*.

*Utiliser* normally takes a direct complement. Here, it is implicit: the direct complement is the object that the warning is on. The English version uses the same construction: “microwaving” could be replaced by “using in the microwave”.

The construction ***au/à l'/à la/aux* + noun** is used for many kinds of tools:

- *frire à la poêle* (fry in a pan), *griller au four* (roast in the oven), *réchauffer au micro-ondes* (warm up in the microwave), …
- *couper aux ciseaux* (cut with scissors), *trancher à la hache* (cleave with an axe), …
- *écrire au crayon*, write with a pencil), …
- *à la main* (“by hand”), “*à la machine*” (using some kind of machine), …

A literal translation of "in a microwave" would be "?*dans un micro-ondes*", but it doesn't quite have the right meaning. It implies that the object is placed inside the microwave but not that it's used for cooking. The preposition *dans* would only be used to refer to the physical location of the object, not for its purpose (“*Où est mon déjeuner ? Ah, il est dans le micro-ondes, j'ai oublié de le sortir.*” = “Where's my lunch? Oh, it's in the microwave, I forgot to take it out.”).

"*À un micro-ondes*" didn't have the right meaning either. You can't use the indefinite article here because that would refer to one specific, but not yet specified object (“*Y a-t-il un micro-ondes dans votre cuisine ?*” = “Is there a microwave in your kitchen?”).

Articles and preposition vary a lot between languages and you can't expect simple translations like "*à* always corresponds to this preposition" or "if there's a definite article in one language then the other language will also use one.

As for the noun *micro-onde* itself, it has two meanings, like "microwave" in English. It's a term in physics to designate a type of waves, and it's also a type of oven that uses this kind of waves. The noun *onde* is feminine, and so is *micro-onde* in the physics sense since adding a prefix doesn't change the gender. *Micro-onde* as the kitchen appliance is masculine because it's short for *un four à micro-ondes*.

Comment: aha! Especially instructive was your example especially of "à + definite article + tool" as a construction that often suggests purpose or manner, in contrast to what "dans un micro-ondes" which only suggests location instead of manner. Could "à un micro-ondes" work in other contexts? (-"There are four microwaves here. What should I do?" -"Just put the coffee in a microwave, okay? I'm busy", maybe uses "mettre à un micro-ondes"?).

Comment: @silph No, you can't say “mettre à un micro-ondes”. The idiomatic phrasing would be “Mets-le au micro-ondes”, or if you really wanted to say “one of them”, you'd say “Mets-le au micro-ondes, n'importe lequel”.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a matter of what to put after "utiliser" and more about what to use before "micro-ondes"

Examples (explained later) :

"Utiliser à des fins scientifiques" = "Use for scientific means"

"Utiliser avec des gants" = "Use with gloves / while wearing gloves"

"Mettre au micro onde" = "Put in the microwave"

"Mettre à la poubelle" = "Put in the bin"

TOPIC 1 :

1. "au micro-ondes" gives a very natural and correct feeling, it's most likely what would be used by native French speakers to say it , so the translation is perfect as it is.
2. On the other hand, you would never ever say "utiliser à un micro-ondes".
   It would sound very unnatural and just wrong.
   "Utiliser à..." would rather be used with a condition : "utiliser à une température de XXX / utiliser à la place d'un four" = "use at a temperature of XXX / use instead of an oven".

Or even "at a certain place" : "utiliser à la plage / utiliser à New York" = "use at the beach / NY"

but never "utiliser à [an object]"

3. "utiliser dans le micro-ondes" would be understandable but would still give a feeling of foreign translation somehow, it sounds a bit unnatural but really not that much. It's just a bit heavy/redundant sounding somehow.
   "Utiliser dans un micro-ondes" would feel a bit better but still not natural...
   As I said earlier "utiliser au micro-ondes" was already perfect, anything else would sound less natural.
4. French nouns are gendered ("une chaise, un tabouret" = "a chair, a stool") and in some cases (like "micro-ondes") the same word exists for both genders but with a different meaning.
   Here it's either male and an object used to heat food up, or female and is a wave of short length.
   There is no real equivalent to that in English (as there is no equivalent to the a/an difference in French).

(again, "utiliser à un micro-ondes" doesn't really mean anything, it wouldn't be used in French and would be considered a grammar mistake)

TOPIC 2 :

> French often requires some kind of object

It's not always true indeed... you could say "je sais !" , rather, "je le sais" can feel very redundant.

In french grammar, there is a notion of "direct object" and "indirect object" that will complement the subject+verb and they can often be dropped from the sentence in shortened, more idiomatic forms.

In "utiliser au micro-ondes", "au" is a sort of shortened "dans le" (which, again, would not sound very good in French), so it already is the "object" and a "fuller" sentence would not sound as smooth and natural.

Comment: On the gender of *micro-ondes* : this word is masculine when it refers to an oven because it is an ellipsis for *four à micro-ondes*, where *four* is masculine. That also explains why it is (most of the times) spelt with a plural "s" to *ondes*, even in the singular. Same phenomenon as eg *un deux-roues* for *un véhicule à deux roues*.

Comment: 0/1. As a French learner who only knows English, understanding what "à" means has been a constant challenge. Websites and grammar books give [ideas](https://www.thoughtco.com/a-french-preposition-1368910), but still not enough for me to understand it. Your examples where à = "in" ("Mettre à micro-onde") or "for" ("Utiliser à des fins scientifiques") are surprising (and therefore helpful to see). This is what I was trying to ask with question 1: how might I translate "Utiliser au micro-onde" to eventually arrive at the meaning of "in the microwave". Guesses I listed are from the linked website.

Comment: 2. So all of these would sound very strange in French: "à un micro-ondes", "aux micro-ondes", "à des micro-onde", "à votre micro-onde"? Should I think of "au micro-onde" more as a kind of short-form of "dans le", and less like "à + definite article"?

Comment: 4. Actually, I was asking if "utiliser à micro-onde" makes any sense, and not "utiliser à un micro-onde". P.S. Thank you for your answer -- I comment not to criticize, but to ask for further clarification!

Comment: @silph 2. yes, all these forms are incorrect. You can indeed think of *"au"* as an equivalent of *"dans le"* since it marks place. But *"au"* is terser and more idiomatic in that case.

Comment: (no offence taken, don't worry, I get it ^^)
1. I think "mettre dans le micro-ondes" and dropping the "utiliser" altogether would be best to convey the exact sense of "in the microwave", as anything else would not sound right (so no satisfying direct translation). /2. indeed, they are all wrong. The only acceptable one is precisely "au micro-ondes" , that would indeed be a short form of "dans le", absolutely right ! /4. "utiliser à micro-ondes" makes no sense at all and should not be used.  A pleasure ^^